# Auto append data from multiple workbooks to one

Tags: excel

A bit of background first:

I have five identical worksheets in different workbooks, each one used by a different person. Also, I have one other person who manages everything that is typed in each of this five worksheets.

What I need to do is: as data is typed in these five worksheets , I want to get this data and append it to a MASTER worksheet, essentially merging the five worksheets on the go.

I know I could just merge the worksheets or copy/paste, but these five worksheets are updated daily, and this would be a great amount of work.

Sorry if there's anything wrong with the post, it's my first time =)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Comment: So, the thing is, there's no code, 'cause I want to avoid doing it in VBA, since other people will be using it and always find a way to screw something up. I tried to do it via regular worksheet functions, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: If there is no VBA and you don't want to use VBA why did you tag it as VBA twice?

Comment: you can look into Power Query or Microsoft Query to combine data from multiple sources.